# Running Ef core migration on the server

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Does any know how to run EF core command on a server with VS 2017.

I have SDK 2.0.3 installed on the server.

I ran this command from source code folder:

```
dotnet exec --depsfile auth.deps.json --runtimeconfig auth.runtimeconfig.json ef.dll migrations list --assembly auth.dll
```

and got this error:

> No project was found. Change the current working directory or use the
>   --project option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Copy the content this files

- ef.dll
- ef.runtimeconfig.json

From:

> C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools.dotnet\2.0.0\tools\netcoreapp2.0

to your source files, open command prompt in admin mode, point to you source file folder and run your command again